# Button Keeps Sticking On Left

Tags: html, css, blogs

I have a subscribe button but it keeps sticking on left for big screens I tried to fix it by using max width, padding but it didnt work. Thanks for help already. I shared my codes on code snippet. Somehow it doesnt look how it looks for me in code snippet so I am adding an image to show you what I meant. I tried index -z too but it didnt work either.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytceX.png)

```css
  /* HERO SECTION */

  .hero{
    background: var(--background-primary);
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: var(--py);
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hero .h1{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }

  .hero b{
    color: var(--accent);
    font-weight: inherit;
  }

  .hero .h3{
    color: var(--foreground-secondary);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .hero .btn-group{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hero .right{
    display: none;
  }   
   
   
   .container{
    margin-inline: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }

  .btn{
    min-width: 10rem;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

  .btn-primary{
    background: var(--accent);
    color: var(--white);
    padding: 0.6875rem 1.1875rem;
  }

  .btn-primary:hover{
    background: var(--foreground-secondary);
    color: var(--action-primary);
  }

  .btn-secondary{
    background: var(--action-secondary);
    color: var(--foreground-secondary);
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: 3px solid var(--foreground-tertiary);
  }

  .btn-secondary:hover{
    border-color: var(--accent);
  }

  
  button {
    font: inherit;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  html {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-size: var(--fs-base); /* base font-size (13.6px) */
    line-height: 1.8;
  }
 
 /* MEDIA QUERIES FOR SUBSCRIBE BUTTON */

  @media (min-width:575px){
    .subscribe{
        margin-inline: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-inline-start: auto;
    }

    .input-wrapper{ max-width: 390px;}
  }

  @media (min-width:280){
    .subscribe{
        margin-inline: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-inline-start: auto;
        width: 1px;
        height: 1px;
        font-size: small;
        position: absolute;

    }

    .input-wrapper{ max-width: 5px;}

    .input-field{
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
     
    }
  }

  @media (min-width:768){
    .subscribe{
        margin-inline: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-inline-start: auto;
    }

    

    .input-wrapper{ max-width: 390px;}
  }


  @media (min-width:360){
    .subscribe{
        margin-inline: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-inline-start: auto;

    }


    .input-wrapper{ max-width: 390px; }
  }

  @media (min-width:540){
    .subscribe{
        margin-inline: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-inline-start: auto;

    }

    .input-wrapper{ max-width: 390px; }
  }

  @media (min-width:1280){
    .subscribe{
        margin-inline: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-inline-start: auto;
        border-width: 10px;
    }

    .input-wrapper{ max-width: 390px; }
  }
```

```html
    <!-- HEADER -->

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="./images/logo-light.svg" alt="Buse Nur's Logo" width="150" class="logo-light">
                    <img src="./images/logo-dark.svg" alt="Buse Nur's Logo" width="150" class="logo-dark">
                </a>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="theme-btn theme-btn-mobile light">
                        <ion-icon name= "moon" class="moon"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon name= "sunny" class="sun"></ion-icon>
                    </button>

                    <button class="nav-menu-btn">
                        <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-wrapper">
                    <ul class="desktop-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <button class="theme-btn theme-btn-desktop light">
                        <ion-icon name= "moon" class="moon"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon name= "sunny" class="sun"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-nav">
                    <button class="nav-close-btn">
                        <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </button>

                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <p class="h3 nav-title"> Main Menu</p>
                          <ul>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                    About Me
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                    Contact
                                </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p class="h3 nav-title"> Topics</p>
                        <ul>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                  New Developer
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                  Database
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                  Accessibility
                              </a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


    <main>
        <!-- HERO SECTION -->
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left">
                    <h1 class="h1">
                        Hello World! I'm <b> Buse&nbsp;Nur </b>,
                        <br> Web Developer
                    </h1>
                    <p class="h3">
                        Specalized in <abbr title="Accessibility">ally</abbr>
                        and Core Web Vitals
                    </p>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Contact Me </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary"> About Me </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="pattern-bg"></div>
                        <div class="img-box">
                            <img src="./images/profile.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" alt="Buse Nur Çetin" class="hero-img">
                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="email" name="email_address" class="input-field" placeholder="Type Your E-Mail" required >
                <button class="btn-primary subscribe subscribe-primary">
                    <span class="span">
                        Subscribe
                    </span>
                    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward-outline" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
                </button>

            </div>

         

        </div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to place that button?

Comment: Remove max-width from .input-wrapper, it will center automatically

Comment: I put max width to not make it take all width when I delete it it keeps taking all width @AmanSharma

Comment: under about me and contact me @Newbee

Comment: also removing max-width and adding with instead doesnt work @AmanSharma

Comment: I add an answer based on @AmanSharma suggestion.

Comment: you need to create a working demo, so that we can provide you correct way. @BuseNurÇetin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why @AmanSharma answer doesn't work. Maybe you should make a playground so it can be check easily.

Below is the answer of @AmanSharma that when you remove the `max-width` from `.input-wrapper` style, your button will move on the center under about me and contact me.

```css
.hero{
   background: var(--background-primary);
   padding-top: 2rem;
   padding-bottom: var(--py);
   text-align: center;
}

.hero .h1{
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   line-height: 1.6;
}

.hero b{
   color: var(--accent);
   font-weight: inherit;
}

.hero .h3{
   color: var(--foreground-secondary);
   margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.hero .btn-group{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   gap: 15px;
   text-align: center;
}

.hero .right{
   display: none;
}   


.container{
   margin-inline: auto;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0 15px;
}

.btn{
   min-width: 10rem;
   border-radius: 100px;
}

.btn-primary{
   background: var(--accent);
   color: var(--white);
   padding: 0.6875rem 1.1875rem;
}

.btn-primary:hover{
   background: var(--foreground-secondary);
   color: var(--action-primary);
}

.btn-secondary{
   background: var(--action-secondary);
   color: var(--foreground-secondary);
   padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
   border: 3px solid var(--foreground-tertiary);
}

.btn-secondary:hover{
   border-color: var(--accent);
}


button {
   font: inherit;
   border: none;
   background: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}

html {
   font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
   font-size: var(--fs-base); /* base font-size (13.6px) */
   line-height: 1.8;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES FOR SUBSCRIBE BUTTON */

@media (min-width:575px){
   .subscribe{
      margin-inline: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-inline-start: auto;
   }
}

@media (min-width:280){
   .subscribe{
      margin-inline: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-inline-start: auto;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      font-size: small;
      position: absolute;

   }

   .input-field{
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
   
   }
}

@media (min-width:768){
   .subscribe{
      margin-inline: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-inline-start: auto;
   }
}


@media (min-width:360){
   .subscribe{
      margin-inline: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-inline-start: auto;

   }
}

@media (min-width:540){
   .subscribe{
      margin-inline: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-inline-start: auto;

   }
}

@media (min-width:1280){
   .subscribe{
      margin-inline: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-inline-start: auto;
      border-width: 10px;
   }
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->

<header>
   <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#">
               <img src="./images/logo-light.svg" alt="Buse Nur's Logo" width="150" class="logo-light">
               <img src="./images/logo-dark.svg" alt="Buse Nur's Logo" width="150" class="logo-dark">
            </a>

            <div class="btn-group">
               <button class="theme-btn theme-btn-mobile light">
                     <ion-icon name= "moon" class="moon"></ion-icon>
                     <ion-icon name= "sunny" class="sun"></ion-icon>
               </button>

               <button class="nav-menu-btn">
                     <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
               </button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-wrapper">
               <ul class="desktop-nav">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                     </li>
               </ul>

               <button class="theme-btn theme-btn-desktop light">
                     <ion-icon name= "moon" class="moon"></ion-icon>
                     <ion-icon name= "sunny" class="sun"></ion-icon>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-nav">
               <button class="nav-close-btn">
                     <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
               </button>

               <div class="wrapper">
                     <p class="h3 nav-title"> Main Menu</p>
                     <ul>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                 Home
                           </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                 About Me
                           </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                 Contact
                           </a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
               </div>
               <div>
                     <p class="h3 nav-title"> Topics</p>
                     <ul>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                              New Developer
                           </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                              Database
                           </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                              Accessibility
                           </a>
                     </li>
                     </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
   </div>
</header>


<main>
<!-- HERO SECTION -->
<div class="hero">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="left">
            <h1 class="h1">
                  Hello World! I'm <b> Buse&nbsp;Nur </b>,
                  <br> Web Developer
            </h1>
            <p class="h3">
                  Specalized in <abbr title="Accessibility">ally</abbr>
                  and Core Web Vitals
            </p>
            <div class="btn-group">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Contact Me </a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary"> About Me </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="right">
            <div class="pattern-bg"></div>
                  <div class="img-box">
                     <img src="./images/profile.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" alt="Buse Nur Çetin" class="hero-img">
                     <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                     <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
               
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-wrapper">
         <input type="email" name="email_address" class="input-field" placeholder="Type Your E-Mail" required >
         <button class="btn-primary subscribe subscribe-primary">
            <span class="span">
                  Subscribe
            </span>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward-outline" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
         </button>
      </div>
</div>
```